# Weird problem. Application started with Process.Start gives UnauthorizedAccessException on writing to the windows registry

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, registry

I have written a wrapper application in .Net that starts another WinForms application with a specified user name and password. For the background behind why I am needing to do this, you can look at the following question that I posted earlier this week:

[How to secure a network folder containing an Access database, while still allowing a WinForms application to connect to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324108/how-to-secure-a-network-folder-containing-an-access-database-while-still-allowin)

Here is the code for the wrapper application:

```
string sysFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
pInfo.FileName = (sysFolder + @"\AppMain.exe").Replace(@"file:\",  @"\\");
pInfo.UserName = GetUserName();
pInfo.Password = ToSecure(GetPassword());
pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(pInfo);
p.WaitForExit();
```

The methods *GetUserName()* and  *GetPassword()* simply retrieve the user name and password from an encrypted text file. The method *ToSecure()* just converts a *String* to a *System.Security.SecureString*.

Ok. Now here is the weird part! :) This wrapper application actually works correctly *MOST* of the time; but for some strange reason it seems to run into a problem right after a system restart. After a restart, for about 5 minutes the application that is being launched (AppMain.exe), throws a UnauthorizedAccessException when the application tries to write to the windows registry. I have no idea why this is only going wrong in the first 5 minutes and then suddenly starts working correctly.

Note also that I have to *close* the application and restart it after five minutes into the boot for it to work correctly. If I just press "continue" on the expection, it keeps giving the execption when attempting to write to the registry.

Here is the code that will throw the exception when the application is started after a reboot.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.SaveSetting("app", "settings", "time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

I have confirmed this behaviour on XP and on Windows 7. Anyone have any idea why this is happening at startup and why the exception suddenly goes away if I launch the application after 5 minutes into the boot.

Comment: Use Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab and start killing processes until you find the one that interferes with your app.  Start with your anti-malware.

Comment: @Hans Passant I highly doubt that this is the result of another process interfering with my app as I have been able to reproduce the same behaviour on three different computers, including a _fresh_ install of Windows XP.

Comment: Well, it only takes 5 minutes.  We would know something more.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally discovered what is causing this problem. I found the answer here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.loaduserprofile.aspx

*ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile* was the missing piece to the puzzle. In the process information object there is a property *LoadUserProfile* which indicates if the user's profile must be loaded, and the default value for this property is *false*. But if the process that you are calling is needing to access HKEY_CURRENT_USER as my called process was trying to do, then this property must be set to *true*.

So once I set *LoadUserProfile* to *true* in *pInfo* then my application worked 100%, even directly after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try using impersonation. Does this error occur if you run this piece of code in the impersonated context?

Comment: Thanks, javros. I will test impersonation and let you know if this helps.

Comment: I added impersonation to my application that is being launched and it did not make any difference; I still get the exception occurring when writing to the registry. I also noticed that the before and after impersonated contexts were the same which makes sense since the application was launched with the same username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Per **ProcessStartInfo.Password Property**  help topic at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password.aspx, make sure you specify the `Domain` property value.

Comment: I added the _Domain_ property and it did not make any difference.